# Reading multiple lines in a file, and separating their values at the same time, to store it in dictionary

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, dictionary

Hello I am beginner in python. 
I have following file as "test.txt"

```
1 2 5
2 6 7

as so on .....
```

I want to read the values and store it to a dictionary 
I have come up with following code but its not working 
as `[x.split(' ') for x in edges.readline().rstrip().split(' ')]`can access only one line of the file.
Also this returns list on which int() typecasting can't be applied.
It can access multiple line in a loop but I would like to know pythonic way to do this.

```
connection = {(int(source),int(dest)):int(weight) for source,dest,weight in [x.split(' ') for x in edges.readline().rstrip().split(' ')]}
```

Can you please suggest the correct method to read this kind of file and then store it in a dictionary.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dict comprehension that's pretty clean, if a bit long:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
  connection = {(a, b) : c for a,b,c in (map(int, line.split()) for line in f)}
```

Note the use of a generator expression to iterate over the lines in the file instead of a list compherension - `(map(int, line.split()) for line in f)` vs `[map(int, line.split()) for line in f]`. This allows us to avoid having to store all of the files content in memory, which can be important if the file is large.

`map` is used to convert all the strings returned by `line.split()` to integers. I think using `map` here is nicer than the equivalent list comprehension: `[int(x) for x in line.split()]`.

Here's the same logic broken up into its individual parts:

```
connection = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c = map(int, line.split())
        connection[(a,b)] = c
```

To be truly equivalent with the dict comprehension, we'd need to create a generator function for iterating over the file:

```
def f_it(f):
    for line in f:
        yield map(int, line.split())

connection = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for a,b,c in f_it(f):
        connection[(a,b)] = c
```